# Mask and inherit the same systemd unit

Tags: systemd

Suppose a package provides whatever.service file so certain events (including whatever.socket) cause a daemon to start with a certain configuration.

I want to disable this completely. In particular, I want the old socket and any other unit files that might refer to this service by name to be unable to start the daemon.

Instead, I want to create my own unit files for this daemon with a different .socket unit and different environment variables. I also want my override to automatically take account of possible upstream updates to the original unit file (which my current solution of copying whatever.service as whatever-modified.service and editing it unfortunately does not provide).

If I create the following symlinks and files:
/etc/systemd/system/whatever.service → /dev/null
/etc/systemd/system/whatever-modified.service → /usr/lib/systemd/system/whatever.service
/etc/systemd/system/whatever-modified.service.d/fix.conf

systemd considers the new service to be masked as well and refuses to start it. How to avoid this?

Answer (score 3):

If you create `/etc/systemd/system/whatever.service`, it already automatically and completely overrides any corresponding `/usr/lib/systemd/system/whatever.service` - symlinking to `/dev/null` is just a special case of that.

If you want to override just parts of the existing `/usr/lib/systemd/system/whatever.service`, taking into account possible future updates, you can create `/etc/systemd/system/whatever.service.d/fix.conf` with your overrides/additions. It will automatically be applied against `/usr/lib/systemd/system/whatever.service` if `/etc/systemd/system/whatever.service` does not exist.

Note that some settings, like `ExecStart=` may appear multiple times, and if you wish to override the existing `ExecStart=` line instead of adding another, your `fix.conf` will need to look like this:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/your/custom/command
```

The first empty `ExecStart=` line tells systemd "I want to remove the original ExecStart parameter, not just add a new one."

And of course, remember to always run `systemctl daemon-reload` after making changes to `.service` files or `.service.d` directories or their contents. Otherwise the changes won't take effect.

Running `systemctl cat whatever.service` may be helpful by showing at once all the parts from which the service definition is ultimately built up.

Comment: I’m sorry for a possibly unclear question that might have led you to believe this is an XY problem, but I do need to mask the original service so units that want to start the old service are unable to do it, as opposed to starting the new service. I edited the question, hopefully now it’s clearer.